# Preview MS Access Report from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an Visual Basic 2013 program which connects to a MS Access 2010 database. After the program calculates and writes values out to the DB, I need to print a report that is in the Access DB.

The code I have now is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1) Then

        MessageBox.Show("Please Select an Institute")


    Else



        Dim MSA As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application

        MSA.Application.Visible = False 

        MSA.OpenCurrentDatabase(fName, False)


        Dim strFilter As String = Nothing

        strFilter = "[Institute] =  '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'"




        MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport("Institute Wise Course Report sdate", AcView.acViewPreview, "", strFilter)

        MSA.Application.CloseCurrentDatabase()


    End If
End Sub
```

but the problem is the report is not getting previewed,please help any body.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code? Is it all executing? If so, break on `MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport` and check the state of `OpenReport` (By clicking the +). Is it open or closed?

Comment: Sir, i could not get your point.How to check the state of OpenReport

Comment: In vb, click on the line I said, and press F9. This will put a breakpoint in the code. Run the application and try and print the report. Your code will appear in vb. Press F8, and hover the cursor over `OpenReport`. A + sign should be visible in the tooltip. Press the + and scroll down to where it says 'State'. Is it open or closed?

Comment: all are executing , while i am using acViewNormal it is  sending the output to the printer directly . but i need to view the report first , so when i am using acViewPreview, nothing is happening. no prweview is coming.

Comment: Is OpenReport a subroutine that you've written?

Comment: NO.It is a method as descibed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx, but acViewNormal  is operation , as described while using acViewNormal  , the report is going directly to the printer, but acViewPreview is not showing the preview.

Comment: Comment out `MSA.Application.CloseCurrentDatabase()`. Even if the preview is opened, it would be closed immediately with your current code.